# Error cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'char' in assignment - C++

Tags: c++, string, function, c++11, struct

So i get the above mentioned error in the line of code:
"women[count_wc] = (temp);"
[Error] cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'char' in assignment - C++

which is inside the function being called.

**Also** another error is found in the place where the function is actually being called. the error at
"get_comp_women(women, MAX_W, array, ROW);" is
[Error] could not convert '(std::string*)(& women)' from 'std::string* {aka std::basic_string*}' to 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}'

```
const int MAX_W = 18;
const int MAX_T = 18;
const int MAX_E = 14;
const int ROW = 89;

using namespace std;

struct data
{
    string name;
    string event;
};


void get_comp_women(string women, int MAX_W, data array[], int ROW)
{
    int count_wc = 0;
    int count_wn = 0;
    int event_occ = 0;

    string temp;

    temp = (array[0].name);
    event_occ = (ROW + MAX_W);


    for (int i = 1; i < event_occ; i++)
    {
        if (temp == array[count_wn].name)
        {
            women[count_wc] = (temp);
            count_wn++;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = array[count_wn].name;
            count_wc++;
        }
    }

int main()
{
    string women[MAX_W];
    data array[ROW];
    get_comp_women(women, MAX_W, array, ROW);
}
```

Comment: I think the error messages should be quite self-explanatory. Read them, and look at the function declaration, and what you pass when you call the function.

Comment: What do you want to do by ` women[count_wc] = (temp);`?

Comment: Change the parameter type from `string women` to `string women[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function accepts `women` as `std::string`, while you needed an array, so, inside the function `women[count_wc]` means "character in a string", not "string in an array of strings"

```
women[count_wc] = (temp);
\____________/    \____/
   ^                 ^-----std::string   
   ^--- one character in the string
```

You need to change your function signature so it accepts `std::string[]` instead of `std::string`:

```
void get_comp_women(string women[], int MAX_W, data array[], int ROW)
```

The second error that you were getting is pretty self-explanatory and means exactly this (trying to pass an array into a function that awaits a string).

Comment: Wow, you're right, thanks alot. The erorr was quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
void get_comp_women(string women, int MAX_W, data array[], int ROW)
```

should become

```
void get_comp_women(string women[], int MAX_W, data array[], int ROW)
```

Both the call of the function and the logic inside it expect an array.